# Downloading Jfrog artifactory throws 403 error[Only non-anonymous users are allowed to access AQL queries]

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jfrog-cli

I am using Jenkins Pipeline to download Jfrog artifactory on a server where Jfrog CLI is configured.

1.The following cmd when executed from Jenkins throws the below error:

```
jf rt dl is-passport-dev/xyz.zip C\Windows\xyz.zip
```

*[Error] the --url option is mandatory*

2.The same above command on executing directly on the jfrog configured server works like a charm.

3.Below cmd is executed as a workaround for Point 1:

```
jf rt dl --url https://<artifactory_url>/artifactory/is-passport-dev/xyz.zip C\Windows\xyz.zip
```

*[Info] Searching items to download...*

*[Error] Server response: 403 Forbidden*

*Only non-anonymous users are allowed to access AQL queries*

This error is seen both when executing from the jenkins pipeline and also on executing directly on jfrog configured server. I have ensured that the user and the repository has the right permission for uploading and downloading.

Note: `jf rt upload --url <url_path> <source_file_path> <destination_file_path>` works fine without any issues

Can someone suggest me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Instead of using `jf`, maybe you can think about using `curl` and passing the username/password as arguments

Comment: Tried the curl command instead of jf for downloading the artifactory and it worked fine.
 `curl -u <username>:<pwd> -XGET https://url/artifactory/is-passport-dev/xyz.zip  --output C:\Windows\xyz.zip`
@MB Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to download an Artifact but you are 'anonymous' (server is not configured in the cli):

two solutions:

1. give 'anonymous' users read rights on you repo (not recommended)
2. Configure the cli with a user and password/token

   ```
   jf c add server_1
   ```

   follow steps to configure

   cmd to use it

   ```
   jf rt dl is-passport-dev/xyz.zip C:\Windows\xyz.zip --flat --server-id server_1
   ```

Comment: Tried both the solutions:
1. Anonymous user is given both read and write permission to the repo.

2. I have ensured that the jfrog cli is configured on the CI server. Also added the following cmds on the jenkins pipeline script :
`jf c add Default-server
jf rt dl is-passport-dev/xyz.zip C:\Windows\xyz.zip --flat --server-id server_1`
But still throws the following log:  [Error] the --url option is mandatory

Both options havent worked for me yet